# Printing hollow square with array

Tags: c++, arrays, border

I'm trying to print a hollow square. I currently have the top, bottom, and left borders drawn but for some reason cannot get the right side to draw in the correct place. I'm  sure its a simple fix but I'm new to this so sorry for noobness.

```
int main()
{
    const int boardX = 10;
    const int boardY = 10;
    char gameBoard[boardX][boardY];


    for (int i = 0; i != boardX; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k != boardY; k++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == 9 || k == 0 || k == 9)
            {
                gameBoard[i][k] = '*';
                cout << gameBoard[i][k];
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: This is what it prints]

Comment: It would probably be simpler if you used multiple loops instead of trying to combine it all into one single nested loop. Then you could use one loop for the top border, one for the left and right borders (print left border, print spaces, print right border), and one for the bottom border.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  Unfortunately I get the same result as before.

Comment: You probably forgot to print the spaces between the left and right border in that code as well.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to print spaces to make the square hollow:

```
int main()
{
    const int boardX = 10;
    const int boardY = 10;
    char gameBoard[boardX][boardY];


    for (int i = 0; i != boardX; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k != boardY; k++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == 9 || k == 0 || k == 9)
            {
                gameBoard[i][k] = '*';
                cout << gameBoard[i][k];
            }
            else
            {
                gameBoard[i][k] = ' ';
                cout << gameBoard[i][k];
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I followed your style to make the changed part stand out, but normally you would separate the construction of the board and printing it to the screen into separate code blocks/functions.